# activate legend filter without clicking in c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

normally when you create a chart that has a legend, when you click on the category of the legend, the graphic emphasizes the filter in which you clicked. I would like to know how to do this without having to click.

[image]

ie for example in my case if I click on "data1" the graph looks like this.

[image]

How can I achieve this without clicking to execute the trigger in a certain category?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) Use the API functionality -->

http://c3js.org/reference.html#gauge-width  (API documentation starts just below this anchor)

In this case, use `hide` anytime after your chart is set-up

```
chart.hide ('data1');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wn3vzn0k/1900/

2) Direct in the configuration

```
data: {
 ...
 hide: ['data1'],
}
```

but it seems buggy e.g. I still see a blue bar in this example -->
http://jsfiddle.net/wn3vzn0k/1899/